# Captcha no funciona con el metodo .change de Jquery

Tags: javascript

La idea es que me muestre por consola el resultado del captcha cuando sufre un cambio el cual obtengo por el método `.change()`

- Javascript

```
$(".validarIngreso").change(function(){
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    console.log(response);
});
```

- Html:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

 <form method="POST">
            <div class="group validarIngreso"> 
                <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="6" required>
                <label><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> USUARIO</label>
            </div>

            <!-- contraseña -->
            <div class="group validarIngreso">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}" required>
                <label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> CONTRASEÑA</label>
            </div>

            <span class="text-danger p-2" id="error"></span>

            <div class="g-recaptcha validarIngreso" id="captcha" data-sitekey="6LcUXbkUAAAAAIwK4Jh4IuFT9j0WgHsHzl0IJPac"></div> 

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar" id="enviar" >INGRESAR</button>
        </form>
```

Pero solo muestra el resultado del captcha por consola cuando lo selecciono y uno de los campos, sea usuario o contraseña, sufre un cambio. Si solo selecciono el captcha, no muestra nada.

[image: captcha seleccionado y uno de los campos sufre un cambio, usuario en este caso.]

Comment: El recaptcha está dentro de un iframe, no se puede hacer así, necesitarías usar los métodos que provee recapcha, supongo que usando `recaptcha_callback` esto te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614606/google-recaptcha-data-callback-not-working#answer-35614875